# How to get Amazon Seller Central orders programmatically?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazonsellercentral

We have been manually been keying Amazon orders into our system and would like to automate it. However, I can't seem to figure out how to go about it. Their documentation is barely there.

There is:

- Amazon Inventory Management (AIM) API: That is supposed to manage orders and inventory
- Event Notification Service (ENS) API: Get order notifications
- Seller Central SOAP API: Upload inventory and manage orders
- Amazon Marketplace Web Service (Amazon MWS): Manage inventory and orders

So hich do I use? Using REST instead of SOAP is very much preferred. Can anyone point me out some better documentation/examples?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think Amazon's API is a confusing mess to deal with.  I just wrote a simple tool to extract data from my Amazon wishlist and it was far harder than it should have been.

I would guess that you want to use the Marketplace service, but I could be wrong.  If you're dealing with PHP, there is a PHP API that you might find helpful - Tarzan (link disabled - this package is apparently no longer available)

Here is a Amazon forum for that should help: http://www.amazonsellercommunity.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=32, and a [PDF](https://s3.amazonaws.com/merchant-facing/SOA-GuideToXML.pdf) overview

Comment: That PDF was the best documentation I've seen so far :) Thanks.

Comment: I totally agree on this, the amazon APIs are the worst thing I ever had to deal with so far.

Comment: Haven't you used the eBay API? :)

Comment: Or http://companieshouse.gov.uk/, is also terrible. Not even well formed Xml (when I last checked ;-0)

Comment: Links are obsolete by now!

Comment: @LeonardChallis I have a long working experience with eBay API and some other providers too, I see the eBay API very clear, powerful and lot enough

Comment: The Tarzan link now leads to some dodgy "Facebook password cracking tricks"

Answer (score 17):

AIM and SOAP are historical APIs. The best choice is MWS, which supports all features of AIM and SOAP (i.e. all listing activity, inventory reports, order reports, order acknowledgement and cancellations, refunds, settlement reports).
MWS is also well documented at mws.amazon.com, and example client libraries are provided for Java, C# and PHP. For feed and report formats, you should refer to Seller Central Help pages for all formats (unless you are a Marketplace seller, in which case the help pages are accessible from your seller account page).

You may also want to peruse www.amazonservices.com

Finally, here's a link to the SOA-GuideToXML.pdf document, which describes the details of the XML feeds and reports, as well as the overall workflow:

http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/tutorials/SOA-GuideToXML.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you (obviously not reffering to YOU) don't feel comfortable with web services and API calling (communication). You can download a flat file from Sellercentarl.amazon with your order information, and use an import method to enter the whole file at once, without retyping any info. Obviously the exact pricess would depend on What system you are trying to enter these orders into.
Good Luck!