# Is there an Amazon API to retrieve order details of a user?

Tags: amazon-marketplace

Can someone kindly direct me towards a way to retrieve information about a user's current orders and order details? For example, a user just bought something yesterday and I'd like to know what it's called and even a tracking number if it's available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Amazon Seller Central orders programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785986/how-to-get-amazon-seller-central-orders-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible for security purposes.